# Word VBA building blocks not immediately available at program start

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I am using some shapes in a document, and recently switched from creating these on the fly (slow!) to using building blocks. I insert the blocks via VBA code, from a form.

The building blocks are located in a separate file.

This all works, but for some reason the building blocks are not present when I load the document, or any new document.  I get Error 5941 "Member of collection does not exist".

The VBA code explicitly references the building block file, which exists.

```vb
Const blockpath = "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Document Building Blocks\1030\16\Building Blocks.dotx"

Dim r As Range
Set r = Application.Templates(blockpath).BuildingBlockEntries("XYZ").Insert(Selection.Range, True) ' range containing inserted block
```

When I click ONCE on building blocks from the ribbon, the VBA code works, and the elements are available.

[image: Image of Building Blocks button in Word, Danish locale]

**Question** What can I do in code to check for this, and make the blocks available from start ?

Edit:

- No "attach template" or similar is added to VBA when I insert the building blocks with macro recorder.
- Before clicking the building blocks button, the VBA project does not contain the building blocks. After, it does.

[image: VBA project before and after click on building blocks]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Word's behavior is to not load Building Blocks until one is called.*

### You can force loading with the following command:

```
application.Templates.LoadBuildingBlocks
```

If they are already loaded, this is redundant but it doesn't hurt anything.

### You could also load your building blocks holder as an Add-In.

This could be done by placing it in your [Word Startup Folder](https://addbalance.com/word/startup.htm) or through vba.

[image: screenshot of vba screen]

When the template holding the BB is loaded as an Add-In, it is immediately available to vba. I routinely add my custom building blocks to my template Add-Ins rather than in the generic Building Blocks.dotx. That way if I have code referring to them in the Add-In they are always there. The same would be true if I added it to a document template.

Here is my writing on [where Building Blocks can (and should) be stored](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#StoreBuildingBlocks).

Here is [my writing on code to insert a building block](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#UsingVBABuildingBlock). The code to use depends on the storage location.